# How can I plot a linear regression with error bars?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a linear regression with error bars using matplotlib. I don't know how to add error bars.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [6, 15, 24, 33, 41, 52, 59, 66, 73, 81]
y = [5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50]

coef = np.polyfit(x,y,1)
poly1d_fn = np.poly1d(coef) #to create a linear function with coefficients

plt.plot(x,y,'yo', x,  poly1d_fn(x), '-k')
plt.show()
```

Comment: `fix the bar codes` - can you explain that?  What is `suma_colap1`?  Please read [mcve].  Have you looked through [The Gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery)?

Comment: It was a writing mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([6, 15, 24, 33, 41, 52, 59, 66, 73, 81])
y = np.array([5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50])

coef = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
poly1d_fn = np.poly1d(coef)  # to create a linear function with coefficients

plt.plot(x, y, 'ro', x, poly1d_fn(x), '-b')
plt.errorbar(x, poly1d_fn(x), yerr=poly1d_fn(x) - y, fmt='.k')
plt.show()
```

Comment: If this answers your question, you might consider clicking the check mark to mark the answer as accepted.